# Compiling OpenCV 3 from source at build time

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Since I need to make Vision system as optimized as possible, for a robotics project, I need to compile OpenCV 3 on the machine it will be running on. But I am doing something wrong and I can't seem to figure out why.
This is my main.cpp (example code):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  cv::namedWindow( "Example 2-10", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::VideoCapture cap;

  if (argc==1) {
    cap.open(0); // open the first camera
  } else {
    cap.open(argv[1]);
  }

  if( !cap.isOpened() ) { // check if we succeeded
    std::cerr << "Couldn't open capture." << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  cv::Mat frame;

  for(;;) {

    cap >> frame;

    if( frame.empty() ) break; // Ran out of film

    cv::imshow( "Example 2-10", frame );

    if( (char) cv::waitKey(33) >= 0 ) break;

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Then my CMakesLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Vision)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(ExternalProject)

set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/opencv)

ExternalProject_Add(opencv
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}
        )

include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include)
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(erl_vision ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_dependencies(erl_vision opencv)
target_link_libraries( erl_vision )
```

Then the error I am facing:

```
/bin/cmake --build /home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/cmake-build-debug --target erl_vision -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable erl_vision
CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(int)'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(cv::String const&)'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:16: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() const'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:25: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:29: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/cmake-build-debug/opencv/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:601: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/cmake-build-debug/opencv/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:647: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/cmake-build-debug/opencv/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:655: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/cmake-build-debug/opencv/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:692: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/home/gpereira/Documents/Projects/Vision/cmake-build-debug/opencv/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:804: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/build.make:95: erl_vision] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:117: CMakeFiles/erl_vision.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:131: erl_vision] Error 2
```

Comment: You meant `target_link_libraries( erl_vision opencv )`, I guess.

Comment: @arrowd I've tried that but it gives me the following error: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "opencv" of type UTILITY may not be linked into another target.  One
  may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
  ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.

Comment: You need to link with the `opencv` library using **library file**: `target_link_libraries(erl_vision <library-file>)`. Look for the library file under *EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION* directory (probably, under `lib/` subdirectory).

Comment: isn't this enough? link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

Comment: @Tsyvarev how do I generate a library file?

Comment: Library file will be generated by `ExternalProject_Add`. You just need to know, where will this file be located.

Comment: That helped me understand whats going on @Tsyvarev can you help me figure where?

Comment: Hm, just let your current project to be built (until the error), and after that check content of installation directory of external package (it is marked as `EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION` variable in your code). Libraries are usually installed under `lib/` subdirectory of installation prefix. Look for file `libopencv.so` or similar under that subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKExamples/blob/master/Superbuild/External-OpenCV.cmake

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get and build OpenCV

if( NOT OpenCV_TAG )
  set( OpenCV_TAG "3.1.0" )
endif()

ExternalProject_Add(OpenCV
  GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git"
  GIT_TAG "${OpenCV_TAG}"
  SOURCE_DIR opencv
  BINARY_DIR opencv-build
  CMAKE_GENERATOR ${gen}
  CMAKE_ARGS
    ${ep_common_args}
    -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=FALSE
    -DBUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=FALSE
    -DBUILD_TESTS:BOOL=FALSE
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=TRUE
    -DWITH_CUDA:BOOL=FALSE
    -DWITH_FFMPEG:BOOL=FALSE
    -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=FALSE
  INSTALL_DIR "${OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH}"
)

set(OpenCV_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/opencv-build)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Your output is not one of compiling OpenCV3.You are compiling your code in erl_vision.dir without OpenCV present on your system and you do not properly install the code you are trying to download(you only have headers, but code is missing which causes linking errors).
I suggest you build and install OpenCV first.

2)No, your OpenCV won't be the most optimized if you build it from source. It may only be newer, but it won't make you a difference in terms of performance.
Since you are on Linux I suggest you to install OpenCV through your package manager(apt-get install opencv* or yum install opencv*). Then All you need to do is is to link needed modules with -lopencv- or use pkg-config for it.

Comment: #2 is just wrong...by compiling opencv you can enable optimizations disabled by default

Comment: What "optimizations disabled by default" namely you are talking about? I'm an OpenCV contributor for 4 years and I can assure you there are 0 optimizations in the provided code possible.